# How to build and install QMapboxGL for Qt on Windows

Tags: qt, build, cmake

I want to use QMapboxGL in my Qt program, but cannot find instructions for Windows platfotm. On the offical github repo https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/qt there's explanation for Unix only.
Please help.

Comment: Given the small amount of source files, it'd be easiest if you included them in your project. Alternatively, use cmake as you would for any other project: there's nothing special about `QMapboxGL`: it's just one more cmake library project.

Answer (score 0):

This repository contains the low level Qt bindings for the "mapboxgl" plugin available since Qt 5.9.

The plugin works on Windows, but currently is limited to MinGW + ANGLE. As of now, Qt 5.9 is on Beta3 and the "mapboxgl" plugin for Windows will be on the Beta4 or Release Candidate.

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/location-plugin-mapboxgl.html